# What's causing the additional margin on my website and why isn't it all even in width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a website using HTML, CSS and Boostrap. I cant figure out why everything isn't even in width going across the page. What am I missing? It seems to be some sort of Margin or Padding on the right side of the page and my card sections are uneven.

https://codepen.io/kennethpaige/pen/zYGzgOj

```
    #<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>title</title>
    <!--STYLE-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--style-->

      </head>
      <body>
<!--TITLE-->
        <section id="title">
        <div class="container-fluid">

          <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">

            <a class="nav-brand" href="https://www.gimkit.com/"><img id="brand" class="gimkit-logo" src="https://i.postimg.cc/SNRNWbVz/gimkit-removebg-preview.png"></a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
              <ul id="navbar-list" class="nav justify-content-end">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#application-questions">Application Questions</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#customer-questions">Customer Questions</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#fun-facts-about-me">Fun Facts About Me</a>
                </li>
            </ul>   
         </div>
          </nav>
       <div class="jumbotron">
         <h1 id="kenneth-paige" class="display-4">Kenneth Paige</h1>
           <img class="gimkit-logo2" src="https://i.postimg.cc/SNRNWbVz/gimkit-removebg-preview.png">
        </div>
       </div>

 <!--TITLE-->      

<!--APPLICATION QUESTIONS-->
      <section id="application-questions">  
        <div>
          <h2>Application Questions</h2>
        </div>

         <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="falese">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active" id="carousel">
            <h3>Why you want to work in customer support?</h3>
            <p style="text-align:left">Why do I want to work in customer support? Well, I believe that we were put on this earth to help each other. I gained a good understanding of this at the age of 11 when my mother had a stroke that completely paralyzed the left side of her body. A week later she woke up to the news that her mother passed away at her bedside.</br></br>
    Seeing as how my father was never around, and I was the oldest of three, I learned responsibility at a young age. My mother taught me how to cook, clean, and wash clothes from a wheelchair, she made sure that I took care of my little brothers, and after everything she went through, she still managed to keep a smile on her face and never let us see her cry. She always told me that I was the reason for her happiness. However, after watching my mother go through so much and still find hope, I realized she was the reason for my happiness. She always thanked me for helping her during that time and It took years for me to realize that she was the one who helped me and for that, I thank her till this day.</br></br>
    When I hear “Customer Support”, the only thing that comes to mind is “helping someone in need”. I’ve de-escalated irate customer’s before and at the end of the call, they always thank me for helping them. The goal is to empathize and understand what they’re going through. You must heal the customer before you can resolve their issue. I want to work in customer support because I love to help others. Nothing feel’s better than hearing that I was able to take someone’s terrible day and turn it into a wonderful day with a delightful experience. 
    </p>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item" id="carousel">
            <h3>A description of a great customer service/support experience</br> you had recently, and what made it great.</h3>
           <p style="text-align:left">I was driving home the night of November 16th, 2019. It was dark and raining outside, so unfortunately, I couldn’t see very well. As I was driving, I heard a loud POP, at the same time I felt my car rumble and start slowing down. After my car came to a complete stop, I got out to check and see what was going on. To my surprise, I ran over a pothole that flattened both tires on the right side of my vehicle. I had no idea what I was going to do.</br></br>
    The next day I called State Farm and spoke with a representative who worked with me to set up a claim. He asked me everything that happened, and I explained it to him in detail. He ensured me that I had nothing to worry about, everything would be taken care of, and all I had to do was pay a deductible of 500.00. I chose to get my car repaired at the same place I purchased it from, a Toyota dealership about 5 minutes away from my house. The next day I called Toyota to see if the repairs were done. I was informed by a technician that my vehicle was ready for pick up however, it had to be taken to another department for the repairs. A few minutes later I received an invoice from Toyota for 2,168.68. I immediately contacted Toyota and let them know that my repair was supposed to be covered as an insurance claim. The person I spoke with told me they didn’t receive an insurance claim, so I would need to pay 2,168.68 or I wouldn’t be able to pick up my vehicle. Not only was it more than I expected, but I also didn’t have anywhere near that amount of money. I called State Farm again, this time I spoke with a different representative. After I explained the situation, the representative told me the person before her set up an insurance claim for my car, but they didn’t cover pothole damage.  I was in a dilemma to no fault of my own, that neither company wanted to take responsibility for.</br></br>
    After several calls to Toyota and State Farm, I was transferred to the manager of the repair department at Toyota. He let me know he understood what I was going through by relating it to a similar experience he went through, apologized for the misunderstanding, and told me he was going to personally make sure my issue got resolved. He didn’t try to place blame on anyone else and I could tell by the empathy in his voice he wanted to help me. He offered to take care of the repair amount and wash my car free of charge. By the end of the call, I had almost forgot about the experience I went through. Getting your issue resolved is always a plus. However, after the experience I had with the Manager at Toyota, I continue to go to them as a customer. He could’ve just offered to cover the repair amount and ended the conversation, but after everything that I went through, I don’t think I would’ve ever gone back to them. Sometimes being a genuine human being is the greatest gift anyone could ever receive. 
    </p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item" id="carousel">
        <h3>A time you taught yourself a new skill to complete a job or project.</h3>
          <p style="text-align:left">I worked at a corporate Verizon Wireless call center for years. I loved my job. However, my daughter was born in October of 2018, and I wasn’t making enough money to support my family. I had to find a way to generate more income.</br></br>
    One day I was scrolling on social media and I saw an ad that stated I could learn how to code, and I wouldn’t have to pay anything until I got a job as a software developer. I clicked on the link and after completing an application I was asked to complete some pre-course work. I completed the coursework and even after I was done, I wanted to know more. So, I studied as much as I could with hopes of getting approved for a coding bootcamp. A week later I received an email stating I didn’t get approved for a loan because I didn’t have enough credit. Seeing as how I could barely take care of my family, I already knew I couldn’t afford to pay for school. So, I investigated every possible option until I decided to take the self-taught route. I wasn’t going to let anything stop me from getting where I needed to be in life. After doing some research, I stumbled upon a website called “Free Code Camp” that not only allowed me to study code but also gives you certifications upon completion. I completed course work and several projects until I earned a responsive web design certification by myself.</br></br>
    When I heard I wasn’t approved for a loan due to financial reasons, I almost gave up. However, I never let it get to me. All it took was some consistency and determination. Studying code is an endless journey and I’m still learning till this day.
    </p>
        </div>
      </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>      
     </section>
<!--APPLICATION QUESTIONS-->

<!--CUSTOMER QUESTIONS-->        
        <section id="customer-questions">
        <h2>Customer Questions</h2>

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" id="pricing-column">
            <div class="card">
              <div style="text-align:center" class="card-header">
                <h3>How do you create a Class?</h3>  
            </div>

          <div class="card-body">
            <p>Hi Mr. Customer,</br></br>
    I hope all is well. In order to create a class in GimKit, you will first need to sign into your GimKit account. From your dashboard click <strong>classes</strong> on the left panel and then click <strong>new class</strong>. On this page you will be asked to enter a <strong>class name</strong>, <strong>class color</strong>, and <strong>class members</strong>. Once that is completed, we will want to submit the information by clicking <strong>create class</strong>. Your new class will be created and ready for you to create memorable learning experiences. I have listed some resources below regarding “classes” in GimKit. Feel free to reach out to me if you have any additional questions.</br></br>
          <a href ="https://help.gimkit.com/en/article/classes-explained-1er5lcw/">Classes Explained</a></br>
    <a href ="https://help.gimkit.com/en/article/how-to-create-a-class-p6aqh6/">How To Create A Class</a></br>
    <a href ="https://help.gimkit.com/en/article/howithwhen-to-use-classes-nvh4mt/">How/When To Use Classes</a></br>
              <a href ="https://help.gimkit.com/en/article/how-to-edit-classes-1ecv0va/">How To Edit Classes</a></br></br>

    Thank you,</br>
    Kenneth 
    </p>
          </div>
       </div>

      </div>
    <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" id="pricing-column">
            <div class="card">
              <div style="text-align:center" class="card-header">
                <h3>Why does Gimkit cost money?</h3>  
            </div>

          <div class="card-body">
            <p style="padding-left:20px;">Hi Mrs. Customer,</br></br>
    I hope your having a wonderful day. All our GimKit plans are ad free, so we offer several plan options in order to maintain an amazing learning experience. I listed a link below to our pricing plans, including an option to use GimKit for free forever. Please feel free to reply to this email if you have any additional questions about GimKit.</br></br>
            <a href ="https://www.gimkit.com/pricing">Get Started with Gimkit!</a></br></br>
      Thank you,</br>
    Kenneth</p>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="pricing-column">
            <div class="card">
              <div style="text-align:center" class="card-header">
                <h3>Does Gimkit have the ability to export a report to a CSV file?</h3>  
            </div>

          <div class="card-body">
            <p style="padding-left:35px;">Hi Ms. Customer,</br></br>
    I hope all is well. GimKit reports can be exported into a PDF file, however, currently the option to export into a CSV file is unavailable. I have included some resources below regarding GimKit reports and information on printing and saving reports. I apologize for any inconvenience. Please feel free to reach out to me if you have any additional questions.</br></br>
    <a href ="https://help.gimkit.com/en/article/game-reports-szolh5/">Game reports</a></br>
    <a href ="https://help.gimkit.com/en/article/printing-and-saving-reports-1m0v2wr/">Printing and Saving Reports</a></br></br>

    Thank you,</br>
              Kenneth</p>

          </div>
       </div>
          </section>
<!--CUSTOMER QUESTIONS-->  
 <!--FUN FACTS ABOUT ME--> 

              <section id="fun-facts-about-me">

                <h2>Fun Facts About Me</h2>


        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="pricing-column">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 style="text-align:center">Things I Love To Do</h3>  
            </div>

          <div class="card-body">
             <ol style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px;">
              <li>Listen to Music</li>
              <li>Watch Anime</li>
              <li>CODE</li>
            </ol>
          </div>
       </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="pricing-column">
          <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
          <h3 style="text-align:center">Fun Places I've Been To</h3>  
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <ol style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px;">
              <li>Las Vegas, NV</li>
              <li>Sacramento, CA</li>
              <li>Orlanda, FL</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  


    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="pricing-column">
          <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
          <h3 style="text-align:center">Hidden Talents</h3>  
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <ol style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px;">
              <li>I'm an Audio Engineer</li>
              <li>I can play multiple Instuments</li>
              <li>I'm a songwriter</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  

    </div> 
    </div>

      </section>
  <!--FUN FACTS ABOUT ME--> 

       </div>  

    </div>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Add `.row { margin-left:0; margin-right:0; }` that should fix things.

Comment: those are expecting results based on your code. No matter which container you are using, you can always try out`margin-left:0; margin-right:0; etc` `padding-left:0; padding-right:0; etc` Please refer to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/ . It seems like you don't understand the fundamental html&css regarding to `padding` and `margin`. You might want to check them out also.

Comment: Also, follow the https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ . I have spot some of mistake you use such as `<row>` is a direct child of another `<row>`, which can cause the problem. the correct practice is `<col>`should always be the direct child of `<row>`. So you want to have something like this `<row><col> <row></row> </col></row>` if you want to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Add .row `margin:0px !important;` to overwrite .row margin.

Comment: Why negative vote? i tried the code and it works xd

Comment: Apparently the the key problem is inside his html code that he does not follow the correct practice of bootstrap grid system. Anything to do with changing the margin especially overwrite with `!important` will bite him back in the future. It could work but it's a wrong fix that can cause more problem. And you are overwriting entire `row` class, that's the worse suggestion. no the downvoter but let you get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

you should use "container-fluid" if full width

you should use "container" if specified width used

this will fix your column view of cards

Comment: Thank you so much! I know I need to work on my code, I'm only a beginner, However the "container-fluid" class worked!